# How to add a background image in css?

Tags: java, html, css

I was trying to get a background image in css
i tried
but could not get that

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* .login-form{
    width: 400px;
} */

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: first java is not javascript they different and for your issue use the background-image attribute check this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image and happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

Hi Utsav Vishnoito to do this it is pretty simple, you use 
`background-image: url("Put your desired image path here")`

EXAMPLE:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    /*IMAGE GOES HERE*/
    background-image: url("https://coolbackgrounds.io/images/backgrounds/index/sea-edge-79ab30e2.png");
}

/* .login-form{
    width: 400px;
} */

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</body>
```